# Remove anthy keyboard from text entry sources in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, input-method

I installed the anthy keyboard for Japanese input, and now want to remove it, but it doesn't appear in the text entry sources list.

[image: Anthy doesn't appear in Text Entry sources]

But it still appears in the text entry sources in the upper right on the menu bar next to the time.

[image: Menu]
[image: Anthy listed]

I tried uninstalling anthy itself using `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove anthy`, thinking that would remove it from the list, but it still is there. How can I remove this layout (so I don't have to toggle through 4 choices every time)?

Comment: Try this: 1. Install the `ibus-anthy` package again. 2. Relogin. 3. Add IBus-Anthy in Text Entry. 4. Remove it in Text Entry.

Comment: I am curious why you have anthy on 16.04 (there should be only mozc). Update from 14.04, or installed by mistake?

Comment: Yes, this is an upgrade from 14.04 @GunnarHjalmarsson Ok, I've reinstalled `ibus-anthy` but had to keep a process running so haven't had a chance to restart yet. I'll get back to you today once I get home and reboot it to try the next steps.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, this appears to have worked, although step 3 was unnecessary as Japanese (Anthy)(IBus) was already on the list. Could you put that comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AliumBritt: Great that it worked. Please feel free to put it as an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment by @GunnarHjalmarsson, I was able to resolve the issue with the following steps:

1. Uninstall Anthy with `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove anthy`.
2. Install the IBus-Anthy package again with `sudo apt-get install ibus-anthy`.
3. Relogin/Restart.
4. (If not already there, add IBus-Anthy in Text Entry, which was unnecessary for me.)
5. Remove IBus-Anthy in Text Entry.

Also coincidentally, my Japanese anthy keyboard started working correctly when I went to remove it, which just figures (I had installed Mozc because anthy wasn't working).